# Nothing To Install is still listed on Stack Exchange as Web Apps

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, specific-site

From the Stack Exchange site list:

[image: Screenshot of SE site list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything on stackexchange.com is very heavily cached.  Normally site changes would show up in a few hours, but I just manually reset the cache so it's there now.

Answer (score 2):

After this change was made, the admins decided to [revert to the "Web Applications" name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates). As a result, the current entry looks like this:

[image: screenshot of Web Apps entry on SE site list]