# Include questions from other SE sites under "linked questions"

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Also display other SE-site links as linked-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/also-display-other-se-site-links-as-linked-questions)

I think the **linked** section should show links to questions on other StackExchange sites when they are linked to.

See, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66617/5190).